# how to merge two elements in one JSON array?

Tags: arrays, json

i got confused by this one, need your help please ...

i have my Session Array like this :

```
Array
(
    [formstep1] => Array
        (
            [username] => sa
            [email] => dsadsa
            [re-enteremail] => sad
            [password] => dsad
            [re-enterpass] => sads
        )

    [formstep2] => Array
        (
            [firstName] => asd
            [lastName] => sad
            [contactNum] => 
            [address] =>   
            [postal] => 
        )

)
```

And i want to be like this one :

```
Array
(
    [formstep1] => Array
        (
            [username] => sa
            [email] => dsadsa
            [re-enteremail] => sad
            [password] => dsad
            [re-enterpass] => sads
            [firstName] => asd
            [lastName] => sad
            [contactNum] => 
            [address] =>   
            [postal] => 
        )

)
```

please help.. i really appreciate any help, thx

Comment: Please post how you're creating this data in the first place. e.g. your HTML form.

Comment: That is not a JSON array. It is not even JSON, nor a JavaScript array. It looks like a PHP array (which, for programmers of any other language, isn't even an array). Please adjust your tags, or clarify your question.

Comment: Uppss.. sorry my bad, that's my session array.. im so sorry